Thunderbird redownloading Gmail messages when started and slow to shutdown
I have Thunderbird set up to check my Gmail account. In Gmail, I have roughly 40 user labels and in Thunderbird I have created filters that direct messages to those folders (usually based on the sender address).
When I start Thunderbird, it displays what it is doing in a line at the bottom such as:
mymailaddr@gmail.com Downloading message 1 of 7 in INBOX...  

It displays messages like these hundreds of times, like:
mymailaddr@gmail.com Downloading message 706 of 1787 in INBOX...  
mymailaddr@gmail.com Downloading message 61 of 234 in INBOX...  

So it appears to be downloading the messages each time it starts.
I thought these messages were downloaded to my local machine but that doesn't appear to be the case if it is re-downloading them each time it is started.
Also, when shutting down, it takes some time, like 30 seconds. I can see it accessing the hard drive. What is it doing during that period?
In the server settings, I have:
Server Type: IMAP Mail Server  
Server Name: imap.gmail.com  

Have I set this up correctly?
Edit:
Thanks for migrating. I did a search on stackexchange and thunderbird and the first few hits were on Web Applications so I went with that but superuser works for me :)
On Linux/Ubuntu, msgFilterRules.dat is here (for me):
/home/(accountname)/.thunderbird/niuka950.default-release/ImapMail/imap.gmail.com/msgFilterRules.dat
I couldn't find that file at first because I was using Catfish file search which is not showing it, for a currently unknown reason. I found it using the command specified in the answer shown below by @Blindspots

If my answer below isn't sufficient, [edit] your question to include additional details about your Thunderbird and Gmail configurations.  Use the linked resources in the answer as a roadmap for the specific settings that would be of interest and should be communicated.  Also, note more information about the message volumes in play and whether you are moving only new messages in Thunderbird or performing some cleanup of older messages too.

Depending on the message volumes involved, you may be doing a lot of redundant synching with the Gmail server which may be contributing to the traffic and messages.
Instead of:

Synchronizing Gmail's inbox locally (to Thunderbird),
then moving messages locally between "folders",
then synchronizing those local changes back to Gmail

You should,

Use Gmail filters to filter and label your messages server-side,
then synchronize Gmail to Thunderbird

Also:

Ensure you have configured Thunderbird per Gmail's recommendationsChoose your IMAP email client  settings for Gmail > Thunderbird
Review the entire Thunderbird support article Thunderbird and Gmail
In particular, the sections:

Configuring your Gmail account
Gmail's particularities

Understanding Gmail labels and Thunderbird folders
Synchronizing folders (labels)
Thunderbird's message lists differ from the web interface
Override Filters & Conversation View






Thanks for your answer. Reading your answer and then elsewhere on the web, I see that the message filters are stored in the file msgFilterRules.dat, but I cannot find the file. I am on Ubuntu LInux. Has this file changed names or is it different on Linux?

See @Jeff's answer to Where does thunderbird store message filters...

That answer specifies the file msgFilterRules.dat as well, which is nowhere to be found on the file system of the Linux machine.

You should create a new question about that.

I found the file. See addition to the question.

So I deleted all the message filters in Thunderbird and created filters in gmail. It still does the thing.

Per my comment below your question, there is a lot of info that would be helpful to know. It's challenging not being collocated because we don't have eyes on the problem. You will need to isolate the problem. Perhaps start by only syncing the inbox. Does that work okay? If so add a a label or two, etc.

Thunderbird is full of bugs that never get fixed. One of which is that it constantly redownloads some messages if you choose "maildir" storage (one file per message). I don't know if this is the case for you, but if it is, try to re-setup your account with "mbox" storage (one file per folder).

While my Thunderbird is not showing that behavior at this time (v115 with Windows 11, Gmail over IMAP and defaults), I have seen it countless times in the ~20 years during which I used it. Bachsau is quite right about Thunderbird's quality, and Gmail may not be better when it comes to IMAP (see https://superuser.com/questions/1852406/does-gmail-adhere-to-the-internet-message-access-protocol ).
